# Andengine and Android SDK versions

Tags: andengine

Hi I am new to Andengine & Android﻿ hacking and noticed that I have to stick with Android  SDK 4.0.3.

Is this a problem?

I.e. when will AndEngine support Android 4.4 and what do I miss by using 4.0 instead of 4.4.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem. It is working all platforms well. Don't worry and start coding.

Answer (score 0):

The platform version setting (Context menu -> Properties -> Android), "Project build target" for application project (you app) and library project (AndEngine) can be unequal. However, the setting for library project must be lower than or equal to the setting for application project.

See http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#considerations for detail.

So, your application can use latest platform version while the AndEngine is fixed at other platform version. (In today, it is 4.0.3 in GLES2 branch, and 4.2.2 in GLES2-AnchorCenter branch)